# chess program and check for legal moves doesn't work and always returns that the move is illegal even if it is

Tags: python, list, generator, chess

```
import chess
board = chess.Board()
print(board)
legal_moves = list(board.legal_moves)
while True:
  move = input ("type a legal move: \n")
  if move in legal_moves:
    board.push_san(move)
    legal_moves = list(board.legal_moves)
    print(board)
  else:
    print("Illegal move! Input a legal move")
```

the issue is at `if move in legal_moves:`, the if statement always returns false no matter the string (e4, e2e4, klsfjds)

since board.legal_moves is a generator of the current legal moves allowed, `legal_moves = list(board.legal_moves)` should create a list of all legal moves, and `if move in legal_moves:` should check if the move is in the list

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `chess.Move.from_uci("move") in board.legal_moves`

Source: https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: perhaps a better link would be to the `Board.legal_moves` property documentation: https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core.html#chess.Board.legal_moves

Comment: works if the user types in notation like "e2e4", but is there a way to make it work with standard chess notation like "e4"?

Comment: @Duel_Clip from my understanding of the documentation, the string is representative of `from_square``to_square`. In that respect, the string "e4" would only fulfil one of those and thus not be valid. What would you expect the move to be from just "e4"?

Comment: @Shorn well "e4" in chess notation would mean pawn to e4, so whichever pawn is able to move to e4 moves to e4. this notation works for `board.push_san(move)` however the issue with just asking the user an input for `move` and immediately putting it into `board.push_san()` is that it does not check if the move is legal or not

Comment: [According to the docs](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core.html#chess.Board.push_san) `board.push_san()` does check for move legality though? Under the errors it includes specific errors for invalid, illegal, and ambiguous moves. Am I misinterpreting the docs?

Comment: @Shorn yes it does return chess.IllegalMoveError, is there a way to check for this beforehand and not let the program run into an error?

Comment: The standard way for handling expected exceptions (in this case IllegalMoveError is a type of expected exception) is with [try/catch blocks (try/except in python)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions). You will "hit" the error, but instead of just getting an error output you tell the program what to do instead.

Comment: @Shorn yes I see now, that method works! Thank you!